# Axios not catching error in catch and weird thing going on in then

Tags: javascript, axios

I have an app in Vuejs with a server in node that will respond to the axios call that the app make.

When the server respond with an error, axios will not catch it and proceed with to call the .then

Moreover the response is different depending on if it's an error or not : 
If it's not an error, i can check the status in response.status
If it's an error, I have to check in response.response.status

Here's an example of what I have to do to handle errors :

```
function post(url, data, headers = {}){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post(BASE_URL+url, data, { headers: headers }).then(response => {
      if(response.response != undefined && response.response.status >= 400)
        return reject(response.response.data.message);
      resolve(response.data);
    }).catch(err => reject(err.message));
  });
}
```

Is there any way for axios to catch a response error in the .catch so that I can simplify this ugly code that doesn't make much sense ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function post(url, data, headers = {}){
  return axios.post(BASE_URL+url, data, { headers: headers }).then(response => {
      if(response.response != undefined && response.response.status >= 400)
        return Promise.reject(response.response.data.message);
      return response.data
    });
  });
}
```